# Select option on a LAScatalog lidR with catalog_retile

Tags: r, lidr

I'm tying to load a catalog and simply re-export the same tiling, but only with xyz attributes, whatever attributes are found in my original list of LiDAR tiles.

Here the code I use :

```
library(lidR)
ctg <- readLAScatalog(lidar_input_tiles_path, select = "xyz")
opt_select(ctg) <- "xyz" # Duplicate
opt_output_files(ctg) <- "[...]/{ORIGINALFILENAME}"
ctg2 <- catalog_retile(ctg)
```

It looks like the `select` option is not taken in account. On the other hand, when I use the `readLAS()` function on a single file, `select` parameters are applied.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is documented in the man page of `catalog_retile`. `catalog_retile` preserves the file format. No way to keep only xyz. The options `select` is not respected. The reason is that `catalog_retile()` is a special, memory optimized, function that by-passes regular `LAScatalog` processing engine behaviour and never calls `readLAS()` and never loads a single point in R. This allows to retile efficiently big files that do not fit in memory

> ### Supported processing options
>
> Supported processing options for a LAScatalog (in bold). For more details see the LAScatalog engine
> documentation:
>
> - **chunk_size**: Size of the new tiles.
> - **buffer**: Load new tiles with a buffer. The expected value is usually 0.
> - **alignment**: Alignment of the new tiles.
> - **progress**: Displays a progress estimation.
> - **output_files***: Mandatory. The new tiles will be written in new files.
> - **laz_compression**: save las or laz files.
> - select: catalog_retile preserve the file format anyway.
> - **filter**: Retile and save only the points of interest.

Answer (score 0):

The filter and select options are not modifiable using when processing a collection of files. From the [docs](https://jean-romain.github.io/lidRbook/engine.html):

[image]

Comment: They are. But not in all functions.